# Ubuntu - use all Windows fonts

Tags: windows, ubuntu, fonts

How, in Ubuntu, would one go about setting up their fonts so that they are the exact same as they would be on Windows?

Note: This is not asking how to install the fonts, but which fonts go with which settings to agree with Windows.

Comment: are you asking for which fonts Windows uses for its GUI widgets, such as a window titlebar, start menu, etc? If so, note that this can change based on which version of windows you are running, as well as which theme you have selected

Comment: as Jonathan said, it depends on your settings. For example, I use big and bold Arial in all Windows dialog, icons etc. And it is not problem to set the same in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

To use Windows fonts on Ubuntu
Which fonts go with which settings depends on the user.
That is, if you only use Windows fonts you will match Windows.
[Fonts common to Windows versions](http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/windows-fonts-by-version.html)
  After you have downloaded the Microsoft fonts package, you can then set the fonts you wish use.

[image: ubuntu appearence gui]

System --> Appearance Preferences --> Fonts, then click on the drop down selection bar, select the fonts from the Microsoft package and set it as the default. eg. Application font,  Document fonts.
 In Rendering you can click on an option eg. Subpixel  smoothing (LCDs) for sharpening of fonts .
 [The True Type fonts from Microsoft](http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/09/09/installing-microsoft-fonts/)
                                                                                         The Microsoft package does not have all the custom Windows fonts.
 I hope this is what you are after.